# tanh activation function in output gate in LSTM networks

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Recently I was studying LSTM networks. I mostly figured out the forward pass. There are tons of great materials out there. I am now trying to figure out how backward pass works. It seems a bit tricky to me. When I was doing some searches, I saw an article on arxiv and something confused me.

[In this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02583.pdf), the author describes the LSTM forward pass and makes the derivations for backward pass. However, he is using tanh activation function for output gate. I could not find any references explaining why he is doing so.

`o_{t} = tanh(W_{xo}x_{t} + W_{ho}h_{t−1} + b_{o})`

Can someone please care to explain me or at least provide me some articles to read? because I cannot find one. Articles and/or blogs and/or course slides I see are using sigmoid function for output gate, which its reasoning totally makes sense to me. An example: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Here, output gate is given by;

`o_{t} = \sigma(W_{o}x_{t} + W_{o}h_{t−1} + b_{o})`

In the same article, he uses sigmoid function to determine candidate cell state (*internal state*) values (or sometimes called "input node" OR the authors call it "input modulation gate", given by `g_{t}`) to update old cell state into the new cell state. Typically, the summed weighted input is run through a tanh activation function (as in this tutorial in this blog post that I linked above), although in the original LSTM paper, the activation function is a sigmoid. I totally understand that and can comprehend the intuition.

NOTE: this post is not a duplicate. I am not asking the intuition why to use sigmoid or tanh functions.

EDIT:  In the article above, it takes tanh function of output gate. But, if you look at one of the articles of Jürgen Schmidhuber (LSTM: A Search Space Odyssey, https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04069, see Figure 1), it says that the activation function of output gate is always sigmoid. I know arxiv papers are not officially published and not peer-reviewed. However, I just want to be sure before I claim that there is something wrong this this article "A Gentle Tutorial of Recurrent Neural Network with Error Backpropagation" by Gang Chen.

Comment: I don't understand how your NOTE is not what you are asking. The reason tanh is used is because of the difference between the "intuition" of sigmoid and tanh....

Comment: By "intuition", I mean, the tanh and sigmoid behave differently when you do the backward pass due to their differentials.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I will  edit my post and try to explain what I ask. I am aware that they act differently and usually interchangeable depending on the structure of problem. Could you see my edit?

Comment: To be honest, there are lots of reasons why he may use the output gate as such. One of which might be a typo. I'd suggest you reach out directly to their e-mail address listed on the paper rather than have people speculate on SO.